# Update parent view when route changes in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm building an app with @angular/material, the root component has a toolbar. The question is, how to update toolbar content(update title, add action buttons or extra toolbar rows, etc.) for different routes?

Comment: use a service to hold the state of the toolbar. Update the state of the toolbar from the component being activated. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. Or use router events to know when the navigation succeeds, and update the toolbar. https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events